# How to store chat history in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do I store chat history in MySQL? I'm using the [CodeIgniter framework](http://www.codeigniter.com/).

I have a CodeIgniter framework website and it has a chatting facility.  I want to store the chat histories in the database, but I don't know how to do this.

Please provide a script or any tutorial.

Comment: How do I park this car? -- What are your limiters and pre-requisites, how will you want to use the stored data? It's simplest to store the chat as a big text blob or similar, with newline gaps for each new sentence but, you can also split the chat into each character and store them as paragraph entities grouped by a chatId, it's pretty flexible until you put on your constraints.... which are?

Comment: Hello Martin, Actually i dont have idea that how i store chat at live time.

Comment: I should clarify that in the above "character" is not a character letter but a chatter person.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on these, i think so you will find your solution.

http://webexplorar.com/codeigniter-chat-example/

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-php-mysql/

Comment: Thanks Imran Qamer, I try it.